# VSSconverter Settings for Migration

Tags: tfs, migration, config, vssconverter

I've been testing a VSS to TFS migration for my job.  The test server that we have tfs installed on has the drives partitioned.  The system stays on C drive and we don't touch that drive.  We have the E drive for our applications.

I wrote the configuration file so the migration would run and it runs fine.  But for some reason it's migrating the data to the C drive.  The C drive only has enough space so the system will run fine.  Here is what my config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SourceControlConverter>
<ConverterSpecificSetting>
 <Source name="VSS">
      <VSSDatabase name="E:\TFS\projectfolder\project"></VSSDatabase>

 </Source>
 <ProjectMap>
      <Project source="$/" Destination="$/Test-Location"></Project>
 </ProjectMap>
</ConverterSpecificSetting>
<Settings>
<TeamFoundationServer name="servername" port="port" protocol="http" collection="tfs/DefaultCollection" />
 <Output file="Migration.xml" />
</Settings>
</SourceControlConverter>
```

Why is VSSconverter migrating my files to the C drive?  I've researched this for a week or more and cannot find anything that is helping me out.  Do I need to specify the E:\ in the destination?  Could this be caused by how the TFS server was configured?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which data you are talking about. TFS stores all data in the SQL database unlike VSS that stores the source on the file system. Do you store your TFS database file on C: drive on that box by any chance?

Comment: I wasn't the one who installed tfs on our server.  So assuming it was a default installation where should I look for the database files?

Comment: If you have access to the TFS Administration Console, you can open it and go to Application Tier and then scroll down to "Data Tier Summary". You can see which DB it is connecting to and then you can find out from your DBA where is the DB file stored. You can find out the steps here too: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/11/where-do-i-find-the-tfs-2010-database.aspx

Comment: I found that the SQL server is installed on the C: drive.  Thank you for your help.